# Are booleans valid JSON

Tags: json, validation, boolean

Why do some JSON validators flag a boolean value as invalid JSON, and others as valid? That is, just `true` or `false` values (no object).

Valid:

- http://jsonlint.com/
- http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator

Invalid:

- https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Got an example of this "invalid" json? Pointing at some tools and saying which do/don't work is rather pointless unless you can show what they're supposedly calling "bad".

Comment: { "booleanExample": true } is validated as it should.

Comment: Updated original post

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The validator you link to validates the JSON string existing of a mere `true` as invalid according to [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627), which dictates that the root of a JSON string is to be an array or object:

> A JSON text is a serialized object or array.
>
> ```
>  JSON-text = object / array
> ```

An unwrapped value such as `true` or `"foo"` or `42` is not JSON *according to that RFC*.

The other RFCs it can validate against, [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-2) and [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-3), deem the above examples valid as it does not constrain a JSON text to objects or arrays, but also allows *values*:

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
> the following three literal names:
>
> ```
>  false null true
> ```

And because the former (RFC 4627) is obsoleted by the latter two (RFC 7159 respectively 8259), `true` *is* a valid JSON string.

Comment: Quick update as of today: the latest RFC (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-3) defines `true` as valid JSON

Comment: @merlosy Still "true" is not parsed by node.js.

Comment: @inf3rno not sure what you meant, but it should work unless it's a very very old node version: `Welcome to Node.js v16.16.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> JSON.parse(true)
true`

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo Not sure why it did not parse true, the current version does it properly.