# AWS CloudFormation template and actual request type mismatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have following piece of CloudFormation template:

```
 //...
"Predicates":[  
   {  
      "DataId":{  
         "Ref":"WAFSizeCondition1"
      },
      "Negated":false,
      "Type":"SizeConstraint"
   }
]
//...
```

Actual request that is coming to a resource from `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` step:

```
//...
"Predicates":[  
   {  
      "Type":"SizeConstraint",
      "DataId":"b62169bc-5cae-4e2b-850d-04d67fea422e",
      "Negated":"false"
   }
], 
//...
```

Why does Boolean become a string?

Answer (score 0):

The above [CloudFormation templates are JavaScript Object Notation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/gettingstarted.templatebasics.html#gettingstarted.templatebasics.what) (JSON). According to JSON [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-2), valid JSON accepts both "false" and false as boolean.

So both of your templates booleans are in your words "mismatch"-ed from each other, but both are valid JSON.  So CloudFormation accepts both.

Refer to a JSON Q&A here:

[Are booleans valid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352207/are-booleans-valid-json)