# In which cases JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> actually returns null?

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm working with .NET core 3.1, C#8 and nullable reference types enabled.

From the class library I'm writing, I'm referencing the version **12.0.3** of the [NewtonsoftJson package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/12.0.3).

I noticed that by calling [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1_2.htm) I can get a null reference (Visual Studio analyzers detect a possible dereferencing of a null reference).

Notice that I'm calling the overload which takes a string and an instance of `JsonSerializerSettings`. I'm only using the `JsonSerializerSettings` in order to handle the possible deserialization errors (via the [Error property](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Error.htm)).

The github source code confirms that the overload I'm calling can possible return a null reference, via the `MaybeNull` attribute: take a look [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/666d9760719e5ec5b2a50046f7dbd6a1267c01c6/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs#L789) for a confirmation.

My question is: in which cases newtonsoft JSON returns a `null` reference when deserializing a JSON string to a .NET type ?

Usually it returns an object of the given type populated or having its properties at the default value for their type, I have never encountered a case where `null` is returned instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the JSON literal `null` [is valid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352207/are-booleans-valid-json), you can reproduce this as follows:

```
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>("null");
Console.WriteLine(o == null); // True
```

Comment: good catch. Interestingly enough, if I try to compile your example inside of VS 2019 I do not get any warning for the analyzers. The warning only appears when I add a second paramter to the call (new JsonSerializerSettings()), so that the other overload is called.

Comment: So we are facing a weird situation. You have reproduced a case where null is returned by the overload not marked as possibly returning null. The only way to get a warning for the null reference is actually calling the other overload (the one requesting the JsonSerializerSettings instnace).

Comment: So, for sure the case that you have spotted is a way to return a null from the deserialization. My suspicios is that either the type annotation of the library is incompleted, or there is some other subtle scenario for the null returning behavior apart from the one that you spotted.

Comment: @Enrico I think it's just an oversight in the annotation, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("null", new JsonSerializerSettings())` acts the same. :)

Comment: confirmed by the Newtonsoft JSON maintainers too. See this issue opened by me: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2366

Comment: consider that aprt the "null" input, there is also another possibility to get back null: writing a custom JSON converter which returns null based on a certain custom logic. So the type annotation is probably accounting for both cases. They also confirmed that the overload having a single parameter is not annotated, but it actually should be annotated the same way.